# lighttpd custom authentication using a php script

Tags: lighttpd, basic-authentication

Is there a way to implement custom authentication in lighttpd using a php script instead of using files/mysql database. Idea is that the lighttpd invokes a php script and based on the result, it can authenticate or decline the request.

The reason we can't and don't want use file/mysql is that password are time sensitive and dynamically changing similar to RSA SecureID.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Could you not use http authentication for this.

A php example:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
    exit;
} else {
    echo "<p>Hello {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}.</p>";
    echo "<p>You entered {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']} as your password.</p>";
}
?>
```

Or covered in the Lighttpd Documentation https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/HowToBasicAuth

Answer (score 1):

Yes, lighttpd supports custom authentication scripts via the FastCGI "authorizer" role.
https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModFastCGI.